# C trying to copy pointer to a new pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I need help with a couple of things:

1. I'm trying to delete a word from a pointer and put it in a new pointer with a new length but i am not able to copy it to the new pointer
2. I'm not sure when should I use the `free()` function.
   when I use the free(str) in the delete function it crashes.
3. After I copy the "str" to the "newStr" what is the best way to copy the "newStr" back to the "str" with the new length?

Please help me understand it, I'm new with this and I googled it, I tried looking here and didn't find something that could help me.

```
void delete(char *str)
{
    int i, indexStart = 0, indexEnd = 0, wordlen = 0, newLen = 0, len = 0;
    printf("Enter the index of the word that you want to remove:  ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    indexs(i, str,&indexStart,&indexEnd,&wordlen);
    len = strlen(str);
    newLen = len - wordlen - 1;
    char *newStr = (char*)malloc(newLen * sizeof(char));
    if (newStr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        if (j< (indexStart - 1) || j > indexEnd)
        {
            *newStr = *str;
            newStr++;
        }
        str++;
    }

    free(str);
    //free(newStr);
    printf("The new string:  %s\n", newStr);
}
void main()
{
    char *str = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    if (str == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }
    text(str);

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        delete(str);
    }
    free(str);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that in C strings are really called ***null terminated** character strings*.

Comment: You also seem to have forgotten that you should only `free` allocated memory *once*. And that arguments to function are passed *by value* (i.e. copied).

Comment: To free memory which previously had been allocated dynamically, the program needs to pass to `free()`  exactly the (pointer-)value it received from the allocating function (typically `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`). This is not the case for `free(newStr);` nor for `free(str);`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [structured programming paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) your functions should solve small separate tasks. But your function `delete()` prints to the console, scans input, allocates new string and fills this new string. But what's event worse is the call `exit()` in this function. If something went wrong, function must to return an error, but not to stop the program. Also names of functions should relfect what they do.

Use `free()` for every memory block allocated by `malloc()`.

So, this is a working code:

```
#include <stddef.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

const char *findWord(const char *str, const char *delimiters, unsigned index) {
    // validate input parameters
    if (!str || !delimiters) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // count words
    unsigned count = 0;
    while (*str && count < index) {
        // skip delimiters
        while (*str && !strchr(delimiters, *str)) {
            str++;
        }

        if (*str) {
            count++;
        }

        // skip word
        while (*str && strchr(delimiters, *str)) {
            str++;
        }
    }

    // if index is too big returns NULL
    return *str ? str : NULL;
}

unsigned countLengthOfWord(const char *str, const char *delimiters) {
    // validate input parameters
    if (!str || !delimiters) {
        return 0;
    }

    // count length
    unsigned length = 0;
    while (*str && !strchr(delimiters, *str++)) {
        length++;
    }

    return length;
}

char *cutWord(char *str, const char *delimiters, unsigned index) {
    // validate input parameters
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }

    str = (char *)findWord(str, delimiters, index);

    // if index is too big, return NULL
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // allocate new string for word
    unsigned length = countLengthOfWord(str, delimiters);
    char *word = malloc(length + 1);

    // check if allocation was successfull
    if (!word) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // copy word
    strncpy(word, str, length);
    word[length] = '\0';

    // cut word from string
    const char *ptr = str + length;
    while (*ptr) {
        *str++ = *ptr++;
    }
    *str = '\0';

    return word;
}

int main() {
    char str1[] = "Hello, my world!";
    char str2[] = "Hello, my world!";
    char str3[] = "Hello, my world!";

    char *word1 = cutWord(str1, " ,!", 0);
    char *word2 = cutWord(str2, " ,!", 1);
    char *word3 = cutWord(str3, " ,!", 2);

    if (word1) {
        printf("word: %s\nstring: %s\n\n", word1, str1);
    }

    if (word2) {
        printf("word: %s\nstring: %s\n\n", word2, str2);
    }

    if (word3) {
        printf("word: %s\nstring: %s\n\n", word3, str3);
    }

    // release allocated memory
    free(word1);
    free(word2);
    free(word3);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```